# Exponential weighting for infinite and finite series

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

in dealing with financial time series, should I consider a dataset to be finite in calculating exponential moving averages?

From the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#stats-moments-exponentially-weighted), finite series should be using the adjust=False parameter. Is this correct, as the use of adjust=True yields different result?